# Concurrent read operations on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, concurrency, nosql

I have a scala application which is accessing a Mongo Collection with 13 million records over 4 threads.

I want the four threads to access Mongo concurrently and want to make sure that they never read a same record. Also, a record accessed by thread 2 in pass 3 should not be accessed by any other thread in future.

Any suggestion on how could I achieve it?

Comment: It could be useful to indicate which lib are you using

Comment: Do you have a `number` type field? If yes, you can use `$mod` operator to split your data into four threads. such as: `db.collection.find({numField:{$mod:[4,0]}})` in thread-0

Answer (score 1):

It looks a good place for a dispatcher feature.

Dispatcher will need to read all ids and then using let's say `roundRobin` queue push ids to `f1,f2,f3,f4`. There is no lock mechanism that will prevent to read data from SINGLE document so when id will dispatched then underling function will have to carry all operations.